# help getting ble-mesh (bluetooth mesh) working

Tags: bluetooth, pi-4, kernel

I was hoping to get some help. I have been working on getting bluetooth mesh working on my raspberry pi 4 for a few days and feel I am hitting a brick wall.

I am referring to [this pdf that was updated July 2019](https://3pl46c46ctx02p7rzdsvsg21-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/1908_Tutorial-How-to-set-up-BlueZ__UpdateLFC_FINAL.pdf) and also [this website](https://medium.com/@ly.lee/install-meshctl-on-raspberry-pi-51aa1e2579e6).

My problem is around understanding how updating the kernel works (this isn't something I have done before) and if the steps are a little out of date.

The reason why I think it could be out of date is when I run the following command I get the version number which is higher than both sources.

```
uname -a
Linux mypi4 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The purpose of rebuilding the kernel is to include the following modules

```
Select Cryptographic API → CMAC support
Select Cryptographic API → User-space interface for hash algorithms
Select Cryptographic API → User-space interface for symmetric key cipher algorithms
```

when following the commands from the medium I rebooted the pi and it was stuck showing the 4 raspberry pi logos on the top left of the screen.

I have then found the pdf study guide which I followed on a new install and was able to get the Pi to boot back up successfully.

I also come across the [rpi-source script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216225) while researching about the kernel and updating it on the raspberry pi and couldn't help thinking that there is an easier way.

I also feel that there is something painfully obvious that I am missing but without the knowledge, I'm a bit stuck.

Hopefully, I have made it clear on my current findings, the main questions I want to ask is;

1. How do I know if the modules are already installed?
2. How do I know which is the latest kernel version for my pi?
3. Do I really need to change kernel versions if I only want to include the modules? how could the steps in the guides be modified to just add the modules?

Any help, advice or pointers on the kernel and Pi 4 would be really appreciated

Comment: What exactly is "installed"? Built into kernel? Compiled and available as a binary file? Loaded into the kernel? Available as source code?

Comment: @Simon do you have any updates to share on this question? I see some time is passed and I'm curious if you found any further success.

Comment: @BenSwayne - no sorry. I was looking at the technology but when the covid pandemic hit I had to refocus on what I was doing.